# Dovecot configuration file errors

Tags: dovecot

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf:

[image: Screenshot of configuration file]

error message:

```
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10- 
master.conf line 82: Unknown setting: service { service { service
```

What do I need to fix to get rid of the error message?

Comment: Please include the whole file as text, not a screenshot.  The error mentions line 82 but you have not reproduced anywhere near 82 lines.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, it looks like there might be a `}` character missing from the end of a previous `service <name> { ... }` block at or before line 82 in file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`.

There might even be multiple `}` characters missing, causing Dovecot to attempt parsing multiple `service` blocks as if they were settings for a single service.

If you are using some sysadmin automation tool (Ansible, Puppet, SaltStack, etc.), this might be an indication that something is wrong with the relevant configuration of the automation tool, e.g. a regular expression that matches more than it should and/or deletes the end-of-block `}` characters.